# "angular2-image-upload" npm library CORS error

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, cors

I am using angular2-image-upload library to upload certain files

I recently upgraded from 0.6.6 version to 1.0.0-rc.1 (Because I will be needing some of the new features in the future) Howerver it breaks down every time I try to upload an image (when it used to work ok).

Errors:
[image]

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.2.103:20005/storage' from origin 'http://192.168.2.103:3007' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

zone.js:2969 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://192.168.2.103:20005/storage with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

HTML Code:

```html
 <image-upload [preview]="true" [beforeUpload]="onBeforeUpload" [extensions]="getExtension(field.encodingtype)" [url]="localEnvironment.apiURL + '/storage'"  [headers]="imageHeaders" [maxFileSize]="getMaxFileSize(field.MaxSize, field)" [buttonCaption]="'Select Files'" [dropBoxMessage]="'Drop your files here!'"(onFileUploadFinish)="fileSentHandler($event, field,imageHeaders)" "></image-upload>
```

I handle my CORS restrictions and even have the typical plugin for Allow control origin.

As I said this same call works perfectly fine with previous version.

¿Any idea on how can I skip this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show that error as copyable, searchable text.

Answer (score 1):

The new version you are using is an 'in development' I believe there could be a few others after 0.6.6 that coulnd include the new functionaliteies you are looking for.

Comment: Only one other version "1.0.0-rc.0" I have also tried it, but same result is given out. But thanks!